# React NodeGUI - Question about technology. Choosing Desktop Platform

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I estimate possibility to write Report Desktop Application using React NodeGUI. There is some questions what I need to find answer before starting to develop by NodeGUI. Could you help me to figure out.

1. What way is to load program extension dynamicaly in React NodeGUI. For example: If I want to change business logic and visualization of my program without compile code. Is it possible?
2. What way is to load program extension dynamicaly in React NodeGUI. For example: If I want to change business logic and visualization of program adding some program module code of other developers. How way is it possible to do?
3. What way is to work with XML files in React NodeGui?
4. Is there possibility to run other program code written by `C/C++` or other languages? What restriction of running non-native JS modules?
5. What way is to connect to `SQL` or `NoSQL DB` (`PostgreSQL`, `Oracle`, `Mongo` and etc)?
6. What are reasons yet to write or not write Desktop Applications by React NodeGUI?

Comment: If this is for an actual production application, you should probably heed the warning in NodeGUI's readme: "This project is in active development. It should be okay for smaller projects but anything complex - electron is the way to go for now. "

Comment: Thank you, Toni. I looked to Git readme. You are  right. What do you advice as expert in JS and Python?

Answer (score 3):

React NodeGui is just another npm module that you would install in a nodejs program. It is a pure javascript library. It depends on NodeGui which is another regular npm module. NodeGui contains C++ code which acts as a nodejs addon. But for all purposes think of nodegui and react nodegui as regular npm modules. An app built with these libraries is a regular nodejs app.

> What way is to load program extension dynamicaly in React NodeGUI. For example: If I want to change business logic and visualization of my program without compile code. Is it possible?

All business logic is written in javascript so any change in those would follow the same flow of how you would in a nodejs app.

> What way is to load program extension dynamicaly in React NodeGUI. For example: If I want to change business logic and visualization of program adding some program module code of other developers. How way is it possible to do?

Yes you can use all npm modules available in npm that works with nodejs.

> What way is to work with XML files in React NodeGui?

You can find a lot of npm modules you can use to parse and work with xml files in the npm registry.

> Is there possibility to run other program code written by C/C++ or other languages? What restriction of running non-native JS modules?

Yes it is possible to run non js code by building them as NodeJs addons.

> What way is to connect to SQL or NoSQL DB (PostgreSQL, Oracle, Mongo and etc)?

You have a lot of modules available in the npm registry for these which work with NodeJs.

> What are reasons yet to write or not write Desktop Applications by React NodeGUI?

Reasons to use:
- NodeGui apps are native apps so they get all the benefits of native apps. They are snappy, they are accessible and run with low memory and cpu usage.

Reasons not to use:

Its under development so is only recommended for hobby projects as of Dec 2019.

PS: I am the author of the library